# how to vertically align text in react native

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

[image: to achieve this]

Hi,

really new to react native. I am trying to align my text so that the top of the '£' sign is in line with the top of the '45'. W3 schools shows a technique for image alignment 'vertical-align: text-top:', I was wondering if there is an equivalent for text alignment in react native.

Comment: Please clear what you want to achieve? Share code if possible

Comment: Check out the Flexbox property: align-item -> flex-start.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox) to achieve that.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.poundSignContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.poundSign}>£</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.value}>45</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 26,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  poundSignContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'// To make the sign in line with top, this styling is not needed, because 'flex-start' is the default behave.
    // It is possible to control the vertical alignment with justifyContent:
    // 'flex-start' - aligned to top
    // 'center'     - centered
    // 'flex-end'   - aligned to bottom
  },
  poundSign: {},
  value: {
    fontSize: 46,
    marginLeft: 5,

    // It is possible to use "lineHeight" and/or "height" to mannually correct the alignment, mainly when the value and sign size difference is bigger.
    lineHeight: 42,
    height: 42, 
  },
});
```

And it should look like this:
[Layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGNM5.jpg)

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. The only thing is when the 45 increases in font size, they are no longer in line at the top. Instead it looks like the £ is a line above the 45.

Comment: HI! You are totally right. The Text element contains a kind of "padding", which creates that misalignment. You may use "lineHeight", "height" or even a negative "marginTop"  styling to manually correct that. Those values may change according to the font you are using. Lastly, I have also updated the code with an example implementation.